# JqGrid Search not functioning

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, jqgrid

This is JqGrid.In here there's a problem in GridSearch.In here i take InvoiceId for the search.But it's not working.But it shows loading panel when i click the Search Button.

My data type is Json.I saw there's a link that is working and i tried to do this also,but it's not working in my scenario. [LINK](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SingleSearchFilter.htm)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(function () {
        $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({

            url: 'Sales/GetAllSalesOrders/',

            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            //columns names
            colNames: ['InvoiceId', 'CustomerId', 'SubTotal', 'TotalDiscount', 'VAT', 'NBT', 'Amount', 'Balance'],
            //columns model
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'InvoiceId', index: 'InvoiceId', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'CustomerId', index: 'CustomerId', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'SubTotal', index: 'SubTotal', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'FullDiscount', index: 'FullDiscount', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'Vat', index: 'Vat', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'Nbt', index: 'Nbt', align: 'left' },
                        //{ name: 'Total', index: 'Total', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'NetAmount', index: 'NetAmount', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'Balance', index: 'Balance', align: 'left' }
            ],

            pager: $('#jqgrid'),
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'InvoiceId',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 50,
            rowTotal: 200,
            rowList: [20, 30, 50, 100],
            rownumbers: false,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            subGrid: true,

            //subrid model
            subGridModel: [{
                //subgrid columns names
                // name: ['InvoiceItemId', 'Quantity', 'Rate', 'DiscountAmount', 'Amount'],
                name: ['InvoiceItemId', 'Quantity'],
                width: [100, 100],
                align: ['left', 'left'],

                //data: { id: id }
            }],
            //url from which subgrid data should be requested
            subGridUrl: '/Sales/GetSalesItemsByInvoiceId/'

        });


    });

    $("#mySearch").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var grid = $("#jqgrid");
        var text = $("#searchText").val();
        var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');

        $.extend(postdata,
                       {
                           filters: '',
                           searchField: 'InvoiceId',
                           searchOper: 'eq',
                           searchString: 'text',
                       });
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: postdata });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should replace `searchString: 'text',` in your code to `searchString: text`. I hope you implemented searching on the server side (to `url: 'Sales/GetAllSalesOrders/'`), because `searchField`, `searchOper` and `searchString` will be just send to the server and your server code shold implement the searching. If you need to use searching on the client side you should use `loadonce: true`.

Second I would recommend you to add `gridview: true` option to the grid, replace `pager: $('#jqgrid')` to `pager: '#jqgrid'`, simplify `colModel` by removing unneeded `index` properties and `align: 'left'`.